# Prevent multiple form submission jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a web app, I am submitting a form with jquery, if I should click on the submit button the first time, it will sub!it once, if I should click it the second time after the first form is submitted, it will submit twice, if I could click it the third time, it will submit 3 times and so on, pls how will I prevent it. Am not talking of disabling the submit button, and I also if I should reload the page if it reset the submission

`$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: data, success: success, dataType: dataType });`

Comment: Sounds like you are adding an event listener inside another event handler. Every time the one event occurs it adds another listener for the event that submits the ajax. Need to see some code for more help than that

Comment: Please always try to add sample code when asking coding related questions

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example. Basically, what you want to do, in your submit method, you want to disable the submit button before you call your ajax. Once the ajax is completed, you will have 2 outcomes, success, or error. In both cases, you want to enable your submit button.

```js
function buttonSubmit() {
  let buttonSelector = event.srcElement;
  buttonSelector.disabled = true;

  $.post({
    url: "your-api",
    data: {
      someData: "kjfgkdjfglkdf"
    },
    success: function (result) {
      // handle your success, do stuff
      buttonSelector.disabled = false;
    },
    error: function (response) {
      // handle your error, do stuff
      buttonSelector.disabled = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonSubmit()">Click Me!</button>
```